# How to find longest common subsequence in multiple binary files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, binaryfiles

I am given 10 binary files and I have to find the longest strand of bytes that is identical between two or more files.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try first and ask issues on it.

Comment: I tried to get the contents of the binary file in a list and applied LCS algo but I am not able to use it for multiple files. Also, I need to return the offset of the found strand in the file along with the file name and the said method is not ideal for it.

Answer (score 0):

- A brute force approach would be to compare each file to any other
  file, which would require 10 * 9 = 90 comparisons.
- And for comparing any two files, you could just run through them
  bytewise and compare if they are equal, and then along the way you
  store the longest sequence found so far. Any time a sequence breaks,
  you start a new temporary sequence and only store it when it is
  longer than the original.
- Another but somewhat similar approach is to use dynamic programming
  for the longest common subsequence (LCS) but requires more memory
  than the previous so depends on the size of the files and etc., but
  for this approach, there are plenty of resources with graphic
  visualizations and pseudo-code of the algorithm.